# Tool to create a pdf report from a visual template

Tags: gratis, open-source, pdf, reporting

My goal here is simple: I want a tool to create a visual template (because I don't want to design by code) of a report (stats,charts etc), and then fill it with processed data from a database (thus needing a language to pull the data from the DB and to make all the processing.

EDIT:
I'd like a desktop tool.

It should work on either windows or ubuntu linux. either one is fine.

It should be a free open-source tool.

I expect it to be able to visually design a report template. by that I mean drag and drop, and WYSIWYG.

I wanna fill it with processed data from a SQL Server DB. I expect to pull the data and process it with a fairly standard language preferably python or C#.

the charts I'd like to be able to display in the report should be pie charts, line charts and bar charts. Ideally the tool would generate them.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want a reporting tool for free, your best bet it's to use the open source ones like Jasper Reports, Pentaho, Birt, etc., however, you must be aware that all of them use Java.

Answer (score 0):

[Syncfusion Report Designer for WPF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/report-designer) will allow you to do this.

This is available as part of the Syncfusion Essential Studio product. While it’s not an open source product, there is a [free community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) available.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.